# codeigniter: Pagination logic to show 2 lists per page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am having a pagination page in my controller, i am kind of puzzled in listing 2 data per page on my view. The controller code which i am using is as follows:

```
public function newsletter()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = array();

    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/welcome/newsletter";
    $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
    $total_row = $this->newsletter_model->record_count();
    $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
    $config["per_page"] = 2;  // per page 2 records
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = $total_row;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';

    $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    if($this->uri->segment(3)){  
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ; 
    }
    else{ 
    $page = 1;
    } 
    $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
    $data["results"] = $this->newsletter_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page); 
    $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

    $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
    $this->load->view('newsletter/newsletter',$data);
}
```

With the above code i am getting 2 records per page as i intended, but i could not understand the logic behind the pagination. can anyone explain me the logic worked in `codeigniter pagination`, with my work itself as it would be handy for me to understand it.

My Model code is as follows:

```
  public function fetch_data($limit, $id)
   { 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ins_newsletter');
    $this->db->order_by('nl_id', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit($limit,$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();

}
public function record_count() 
{
    return $this->db->count_all("ins_newsletter");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean why page 1 is showing first two records, page 2 is showing the next two records?

Comment: @ChrisLam, yeah buddy, we do not know the logic behind it, we simply followed a tutorial in net and implied it.. Can you detail it how page 1 is showing first two records, page 2 is showing the next two records? and so on...

Comment: It will help the community as well , whoever does not know can grab the logic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI's Paginator class only generates pagination links for you.

The "record pagination" logic happens here:

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
```

`$limit` is the **number of records** to fetch, `$offset` is the **offset of the first row to return**.

To fetch the first two records, we will set `$limit` = 2, `$offset` = 0

CI translates into SQL like:

```
SELECT ...... FROM ins_newsletter LIMIT 0, 2;
```

To fetch record number 3 and 4, we will set `$limit` = 2, `$offset` = 2

CI translates into SQL like:

```
SELECT ...... FROM ins_newsletter LIMIT 2, 2;
```

---

**Edit:**

There is a small bug in your code.

The offset should be 0 for page 1, 2 for page 2, 4 for page 3, 6 for page 4, 8 for page 5...and so on.

```
public function fetch_data($limit, $page)
{
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    ...
}
```

And I would suggest you to change the second param to `$page` instead of `$id`.

Comment: The above query is not giving the latest record for us.. why?

Comment: Ok i get the latest record, but i missed the last one.. I have 4 records in my db